# After go vet occurs named files must all be in one directory;

Tags: go, directory-structure

After using go vet **/*.go occurs named files must all be in one directory;
What i need to do to fix it?My project structure looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`./...` is the way golang treat a tree recursively. try `go vet ./...` instead

Comment: To check this project i need use goimports and golint too. As i understand commands should look like 'goimports (double wildcard)/(single wildcard).go' and 'golint ./...'. Goimports must looks like because it's doesnt works with ./... and any way it has output with formatted code. Golint occurs the same error like go vet.

Comment: `goimports ...` and `golint ...` both works file for me